# how to set a databound drop down list to allow empty string when it is bound to a primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

Hi i have a drop down list that is populated by a table where the primary key is what determines the value of the item.

How can i create an empty string item in the drop down list when the primary key of the datasource table does not allow nulls?

basically i just want to allow the user of my application the choice of uploading a document or not which is currently not possible because the drop down list only shows items on the list with the default item already selected.

I have managed to create an empty string in the drop down list but this does no good because the table requires a non null choice.

thanks

UPDATE

I took out my try/catch statement and received this error!

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "Network equipment - Attachments". The conflict occurred in database "Asset management System DB", table "dbo.Attachments", column 'AttachmentID'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: The database field is not nullable, yet you want the option of an empty value in the dropdown? Then you must perform client- (and perferably server- as well) side validation, to force the user to select a value.

Answer (score 0):

you can insert -1 or 99 something like that in the table column.

```
 ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "-1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert new item in dropdown with value 0 like this

```
 ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "0"));
```